# Session time out Logout Url ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, session-timeout

I have an issue with my ASP.Net web app built in 4.0 framework.
I have the below set in the web config -

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SignIn.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

when a user clicks my url he sees the login page.
Now the **session timeout** is set to the default session time out from **IIS** which is **20 minutes**.
Now when the **session expires** I would like to force the user to redirect to **Logout.aspx**

How can I achieve this? I would like to redirect the user to Logout.aspx page once the session times out.

Comment: The only way I know to do this is to create an AJAX method that calls a service/action to determine whether or not the user is still logged in.

Comment: Why do they need to redirect to logout? if the user's session has expired, they'll have to sign in again. Are you doing something in the logout?

Comment: yes we have custom logic at logout.

Comment: What if i add response.redirect("logout.aspx") at the Session_End event in global.asax- would that work ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to check HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession on each page request to see if the user's session timed out and has started a new session. In the event that it is a new session, redirect the user to the page of your choosing.

If you're using MVC or even just want to see a more thorough explanation of session timeouts in action, check out http://tyronedavisjr.com/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/ for an example.

Comment: Not using MVC. is it that complicated. isnt there a simpler approach ?

Comment: If you're looking to do something in an automated way where if the page is on the users screen and they go idle, you'll need to create a AJAX approach where you poll a ASPX page periodically and have it check the IsNewSession prop for you and then respond to the AJAX request so some action can be taken.

Comment: What if i add response.redirect("logout.aspx") at the Session_End event in global.asax- would that work ?

Comment: @JustinRusso No because that is a server event, not a client side event.  If you want the client to be logged out; you have to do this via javascript on the client side.